# Custom post type loop with custom category filtering

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query

Can anyone help me here. I want to list all the custom posts with the type 'portfolio' in this loop, where they have the 'Project Categories' set to 'ABC'. The below doesn't work, I think the issue is that the '' array parameter is looking at the main WP 'Categories'. Can someone help me to get it working please? Cheers.

```php
$loop = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'post_type'      => 'portfolio',
        'posts_per_page' => 50,
        'category_name'  => 'ABC',
    )
);

while ( $loop->have_posts() ) :
    $loop->the_post();
    ?>

    <div class="half-column">
        <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
    </div>

<?php endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Answer (score 1):

Is that **category** or custom **taxonomy**?

if this is a category, then try this one.

```php
<?php
$loop = new WP_Query(
array(
    'post_type' => 'portfolio',
    'posts_per_page' => 50,
    'category__in' => array('8','9','10'), // your category ids
)
);
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

?>

<div class="half-column">
<h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
</div>

<?php endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Or if this **custom taxonomy**, try this one

```php
<?php
$loop = new WP_Query(
array(
    'post_type' => 'portfolio',
    'posts_per_page' => 50,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array (
            'taxonomy' => 'yourTaxonomy',
            'field' => 'slug', //type, id or slug
            'terms' => 'yourTermSlug',
        )
    ),
)
);
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

?>

<div class="half-column">
<h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
</div>

<?php endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

let me know the update.
Thank You

Comment: `'project-type' => 'ABC'` worked for me in the end.

Comment: Okay,
If this is work for you, please mark this as solved.
Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me `'project-type' => 'ABC'`